# Connecting academic license for Bruker TopSpin 3.6 to CodeMeter

Tags: 20.04

I believe I have both TopSpin3 and CodeMeter working properly. At least, I can go to the WebAdmin interface for CodeMeter and see that my academic license is installed.

I can also install TopSpin3 using the instructions at: https://selkieupsilon.blogspot.com/2020/06/installing-bruker-topspin-4-on-ubuntu.html

But when I start TopSpin, I get this error message:

CodeMeter initialization error 126: Loading CodeMeter shared library failed

and it requests that I install a License Ticket. I have already done that. If I re-enter the ticket number, I can see:

TopSpin4 Processing Only (academia license, 3y) incl. TopSpin3  2022-04-12 13:52:19     XXX-XXXXXXXX    Available: 0 (1)

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Thank you for any help. :)

TopSpin 4.1 works immediately and the license is connected, so the issue of connecting the license via CodeMeter is aparently only with TopSpin 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I run in the same Topspin 3.6 problem recently.

To solve it I realize that Topspin 3 is a 32bits binary, so I just had to install the 32bits version of Wibu Codemeter alongside with the 64bits one.

Hope it will help,
Vince.